# Recommended Deployment for JavaFX Jars (Netbeans)?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an issue in Netbeans 17 where I really can't deploy .jar files outside the Netbeans environment.

I have a vanilla Netbeans maven project that I'm interesting in deploying to other systems. Is there a way to make a self-contained jar from Netbeans without too much work? So far I already have an executable jar from a maven plugin, but since JavaFX was removed from the JDK, despite the maven dependencies, they don't seem to make it into the compiled .jar file for some reason.

Is there an easy way to do this? I just want to launch a JavaFX gui from outside the Netbeans environment for users?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPKxqc8Zg-0

Comment: @Gantendo That's locked to Windows OS's though...

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for
[Chapter 6 Self-Contained Application Packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm)
and see especially the section of
[6.3.2 Basic Build](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#BCGGACFA).

The main advice is to modify the deployment task by addding
`nativeBundles="all"` to the
[<fx:deploy>](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm#CIABIFCI)
task.

To specify the package format to produce use the value `image`
whose possible values are specified in
`<fx:deploy>` as all, deb, dmg, exe, image, msi, none, rpm.

For more information, see the documentation.

Comment: Yes, but the project is using Maven, not Ant to manage dependencies.

Comment: For Maven, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036607/bundle-native-dependencies-in-runnable-jar-with-maven) might help.